# Rsync adding a "?" at the beginning of directories

Tags: files, directory, rsync

I currently have many of these commands running in a `.sh` file that looks like this:

```
rsync -avz -e ssh --rsh='ssh -p1337' --bwlimit=10000 root@DestinationIP:/home/backup /home/localbackup
rsync -avz -e ssh --rsh='ssh -p1337' --bwlimit=10000 root@DestinationIP:/home/backup2 /home/localbackup2
```

When I go to run this, it goes through to the destination correctly, but adds a "?" to the beginning of the directory locally, which prompty fills up the hard drive to the brim.

Have I done a flag incorrectly? I thought `rsync` was supposed to sync the directories, not duplicate them.

Comment: At the beginning? It doesn't (seem to) create directories called `/home/localbackup?/backup` and `/home/localbackup2?/backup2`?

Comment: If running the commands manually works fine, what does your .sh file actually look like?  And are you using bash or another shell?

Comment: the `-e ssh --rsh=...` seems strange - `-e` is a synonym for `--rsh`.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at the man pages for `rsync`.

There is a section in there that has the following:

> The  file-types  that replace the X are: f for a file, a d for a
>                 directory, an L for a symlink, a D for a device, and a S  for  a
>                 special file (e.g. named sockets and fifos).
>
> ```
>           The  other  letters  in  the string above are the actual letters
>           that will be output if the associated attribute for the item  is
>           being  updated or a "." for no change.  Three exceptions to this
>           are: (1) a newly created item replaces each letter with  a  "+",
>           (2)  an identical item replaces the dots with spaces, and (3) an
>           unknown attribute replaces each letter with a "?" (this can hap-
>           pen when talking to an older rsync).
> ```

Start there and report back!

Comment: What's odd is that when I perform the commands in turn, they work out fine, am I doing something wrong in the .sh?

Comment: Im not certain, is what you posted (the two lines of rsync) your .sh file?  If so, then yes, you have some problems in there.  If you just copied two lines out of your .sh, then I can't answer that I'd have to see the entire thing.